# Анимация нескольких Button по очереди в Android

Tags: android, анимация

дорогие друзья. Пожалуйста помогите мне... Есть 14 кнопок Button, и они должны появляться по очереди, с анимацией, плавное увеличение и уменьшение и в конце нормальное состояние, ну как сказать, типа как импульс плавное, и не все сразу по постепенно, 1-ое потом через 150 мс 2-ое и потом через 300 мс 3-ое и тг далее.

Если пример, то есть приложения 4 Фотки 1 Слово и там кнопки для выбора появляются анимацией, точно так же хочу и я сделать появления разных элемент и кнопок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть штатные средства:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myButton.setAnimation(myAnim);

//и там где надо стартуем анимацию:
 myButton.startAnimation(myAnim);
```

анимация описывается в XML ресурсе в каталоге `res/anim`

Дальше читайте мануалы, документацию вгрызайтесь в гранит - удачи.

Comment: Вы не правильно меня поняли, я прописал анимацию и надо было по последовательности применять анимацию и с условием, что есть или нет, то продолжить анимацию, НО Я УЖЕ ВСЁ САМ НАКОДИЛ и для этого создал функцию и применил анимацию AnimationListener

Comment: ну какой вопрос - такой и ответ, а то сами накодили - ну молодца, так держать